# Override extends in smarty template

Tags: smarty, smarty3

In the top of my orders.tpl I have

```
{extends "common/main.tpl"}
```

to show the order inside the usual header, footer, menu etc on the page.
I call the page the usual way:

```
$smarty->display(TMPLDIR.'/customer/order.tpl');
```

But now I want to get the same order without the "wrapping" of header,footer and menu into a mail with

```
$mailbody = $smarty->fetch(TMPLDIR.'/customer/order.tpl');
```

Is it possible, or do I need to make a copy  for email only?

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a variable to smarty before parsing the template, i.e.

```
$smarty->assign('only_content',true);
```

and then in your order.tpl template add some conditions for the blocks you want to ignore:

```
{if !$only_content}
<header>.... </header>
{/if}
```

and so on